# Importing a lzo file into java spark as dataset

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, lzo

I have some data in tsv format compressed using lzo. Now, I would like to use these data in a java spark program.

At the moment, I am able to decompress the files and then import them in Java as text files using

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[2]")
            .appName("MyName")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> input = spark.read()
            .option("sep", "\t")
            .csv(args[0]);

    input.show(5);   // visually check if data were imported correctly
```

where I have passed the path to the decompressed file in the first argument. If I pass the lzo file as an argument, the result of show is illegible garbage.

Is there a way to make it work? I use IntelliJ as an IDE and the project is set-up in Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It consists of two parts: installing the hadoop-lzo package and configuring it; after doing this, the code will remain the same as in the question, provided one is OK with the lzo file being imported in a single partition.

In the following I will explain how to do it for a maven project set up in IntelliJ.

- Installing the package hadoop-lzo: you need to modify the `pom.xml` file that is in your maven project folder. It should contain the following excerpt:

  ```
  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>twitter-twttr</id>
          <url>http://maven.twttr.com</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
          <!-- Apache Spark main library -->
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <!-- Packages for datasets and dataframes -->
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hadoop.gplcompression/hadoop-lzo -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.hadoop.gplcompression</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-lzo</artifactId>
          <version>0.4.20</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ```

This will activate the maven Twitter repository that contains the package [hadoop-lzo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hadoop.gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.20) and make hadoop-lzo available for the project.

- The second step is to create a `core-site.xml` file to tell hadoop that you have installed a new codec. It should be placed somewhere in the program folders. I put it under `src/main/resources/core-site.xml` and marked the folder as a resource (right click on the folder from the IntelliJ Project panel -> Mark Directory as -> Resources root). The `core-site.xml` file should contain:

  ```
  <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
          <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,
              com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,
              com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,
              org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
              org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec</value>
      </property>
      <property>
          <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
          <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
  ```

And that's it! Run your program again and it should work!

Comment: I tried the above, but getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: native-lzo library not available` and `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path`