# Can't import lzo files in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lzo

I have a csv file compressed in lzo format and I want to import it into a pyspark dataframe. Were the file not compressed, I would simply do:

```
import pyspark as ps

spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
data = spark.read.csv(fp, schema=SCHEMA, sep="\t")
```

where the file path `fp` and schema `SCHEMA` are properly defined elsewhere. When the file is compressed with lzo, however, this returns a dataframe filled with `null` values.

I have installed lzop on my machine and can decompress the file from the terminal then import it using pyspark. However, that's not a feasible solution due to hard disk space and time constraints (I have tons of lzo files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a long time but I found a solution. I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438127/5048010) and tried to reproduce by hand what Maven does with Java.

These are the steps to follow:

1. Find the pyspark home folder: one way of doing it on Ubuntu is to run from terminal the command `locate pyspark/find_spark_home.py`; if it fails, make sure you installed pyspark and run the command `sudo updatedb` before trying again to use `locate`. (Make sure you select the correct installation of pyspark: you might have more than one, especially if you use virtual environments.)
2. Download the hadoop-lzo jar from [this maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hadoop.gplcompression/hadoop-lzo?repo=twitter) and place it inside the `$pyspark_home/jars` folder.
3. Create the folder `$pyspark_home/conf`.
4. Inside this folder, create a `core-site.xml` file containing the following text:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
           <value>
               org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,
               com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,
               com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,
               org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
               org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
           </value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
           <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
       </property>
   </configuration>
   ```

Now the code in the question should work properly.

Comment: I am trying to use your approach here but I get the following when creating core-site.xml: `ERROR GPLNativeCodeLoader: Could not load native gpl library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path`